# How can I quickly retrieve the Semantic Scholar IDs of all my co-authors?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, authorship, conflict-of-interest

Some conference is asking me to:

> Please enter the Semantic Scholar IDs of everyone who may be biased in reviewing your submission. These should include people like supervisors, family members, intimate friends, and students.

That's a pain to do it manually. How can I quickly retrieve the Semantic Scholar IDs of all my co-authors? (e.g., programmatically or some other tricks)

(I know that the set {"people like supervisors, family members, intimate friends, and students"} is slightly different from {"my co-authors"} but that's good enough for me.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of DOIs of your papers, you could do this using the [Semantic Scholar API](https://api.semanticscholar.org/), or [this unofficial Python interface for it](https://github.com/danielnsilva/semanticscholar).

For a query using the DOI, you get a JSON object (or a dictionary with the Python API) that contains the list of author names and IDs.